# PFObject uploaded flag

Tags: parse-platform, pfobject, local-datastore

I've got an iOS app that should display whether a PFObject has been uploaded or is merely pinned in the Local Datastore. Is there a flag for that? Do I have to make my own?

Comment: What do you mean by _display_ and what do you mean by uploaded (by the user or you?). You can manually invoke a flag for pinned items since your the one doing the pinning, you can set a flag simultaneously.

Comment: @soulshined By display, I want to convey to the user that an object created locally hasn't yet been uploaded with a progress spinner (or something less annoying). By uploaded, I mean the object exists in the cloud. Since my app is social, the objects in question can be liked/commented on, so it's important to know if they're on the cloud. I was hoping there was some easy flag pre-made for PFObject that would tell me that, but I suppose not.

Comment: Yes, thats what &error is for. It will tell you if it successfully uploaded or not. As far as the user end of uploading something then yes, a progress HUD is an option. As far as liking/commenting, obviously users won't be able to like/comment on it if it's not in the cloud or otherwise. I think you just may be making this harder on yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the answer is to check the objectId. If it's non-nil, then it's been uploaded to the cloud database. :D